# Is it there a reason not to use a JavaScript object literal for conditionally returning functions over a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, python, if-statement, switch-statement

I have been thinking about the lack of the the switch statement in Python and wondered if the work around, using a Python dictionary, could be approached in the same way in JavaScript using an Object literal?

In JavaScript, I have traditionally seen switch statements or even if / else statements used for conditionally returning functions.

```
switch(service) {
    case 'netflix':
        return netflix_service();
}....
```

I am wondering wondering whether you can just use the object literal in JS, which to me at least seems more syntactically concise. For example:

```
services = {
  netflix: netflix(),
  ...
};
```

But is there a reason that I keep seeing switch statements or if / else statements over the object literal approach? Whether performance or convention?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your object literal values should be *references* to the functions, and not *calls* to the functions.

Comment: @Pointy unless the functions being invoked are factory functions that return each service.

Comment: Are you asking about Javascript or Python? I can't tell.

Comment: Does it work? Is it readable and maintainable? Does profiling say it's fast enough?

Comment: I was asking specifically about the "JavaScript object literal". I will tidy up the grammar.

Comment: @byxor yes I agree that's possible. However, note the second snippet of code.

Comment: Just to understand better are you asking if it's possible call one of these functions in a concise way using an object literal?

Comment: Thanks Racil, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no noticeable performance difference between using `if...else`, `switch`, or a dictionary of functions (but see the first comment by Pointy). Unless you put your code in a loop of 1 million, it's not even worth talking about it. So it all comes down to the code readability. For more than two options, `switch` and dictionary of functions look much better than `if...else`. Consider these two snippets:

```
switch(service) {
    case 'netflix':
        return netflix_service();
    case 'facebook':
        return facebook_service();
    case 'youtube':
        return youtube_service();
}

if(service == 'netflix')
        return netflix_service();
else if(service == 'facebook')
        return facebook_service();
else if(service == 'youtube')
        return youtube_service();
```

The good news is that `switch` happens to be also faster than `if...else`.